# .NET Profiler - Getting The Type Of A Function Parameter

Tags: .net, clr-profiling-api

I've implemented the .Net Profiler callback which allows me to get data about all the functions called in a .NET application. The function callback works great. Starting in the callback, I make a call to

`GetModuleMetaData(moduleId, ofRead, IID_IMetaDataImport, (IUnknown**)&metaDataImport);`

to which I make a subsequent call to

`metaDataImport->EnumParams(&phEnum, (mdMethodDef)metaDataToken, rParams, cMax, &pcTokens);`

pcTokens contains an array of parameter reference tokens. I can use those tokens to get the parameter names with the following call.

`metaDataImport->GetParamProps(rParams[i], &(mdMethodDef)metaDataToken, &pulSequence, szName3, cchName3, &pchName3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

I'm stuck at trying to find the type of each parameter. I can't find any documentation that would give me the parameter type. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/imetadataimport-interface

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive [CorElementType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/corelementtype-enumeration) of the parameter,
you can do it by signature parsing. Each method has signature with types of all locals and parameters.
By `GetSigFromToken` or `GetMethodSpecProps` (for `methodSpec`) you can receive the signature.

After that you can parse the signature and extract the needed information.
I recommend you to read `I.8.6.1 Signatures` of `ECMA-355`, especially `I.8.6.1.5 Method signatures` paragraph, to understand the format of the signature.

Here is an [example of type parser in c#](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Linq.Expressions/tests/ILReader/SigParser.cs) or [c++ parser by David Broman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davbr/sigparse-cpp).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any idea if there is a simpler way to just get a string of the type?

Basically when enumerating the parameters, I'm just looking to do a quick check if the type is a string or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no easier way. Unfortunately there is no built-in Type-parser in .net profiler API.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Once you are able to parse the function's parameter types, any idea how to determine what sizes they are?

I followed the example you sent in which i was able to determine the type of the function parameter. I have the memory address to where the actual parameters lie, but i don't know how to traverse the memory addresses and get each parameter value.


Is a ELEMENT_TYPE_STRING 8 bytes? Is a ELEMENT_TYPE_PTR 4 bytes? How would I find out the size of each parameter?


Thanks again for any info you can provide.

Comment: ELEMENT_TYPE_PTR is a type of the parameter, like ELEMENT_TYPE_I4 or ELEMENT_TYPE_STRING, it is not a size of the parameter.
I think this guide can help you to understand more about signatures, how it is represented in a blob, memory and compressed integer for a metadata extracting from the signature.

 Part 1: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42649/NET-File-Format-Signatures-Under-the-Hood-Part-1-o
 Part2: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42655/NET-File-Format-Signatures-under-the-Hood-Part-2-o

Comment: In regards to parsing _COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO structure, the structure has the memory segments which contains the functions parameter values. After parsing the signature to get each parameter type, it seems like I would also need to determine the size of each parameter to extract the parameter data from the memory segments of that structure.